# How to Pass variable to another page using Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, angular-controller

I have a HTLM table that contains information about persons ( id,name,..). I made the name act as a link to another page, so when I press the name of any person I want to pass the id of this person to another php page to work with it.
Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter:search:restrict">
    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
    <td><button  ng-controller ="direct" class="btn btn-link" ng-click = "sendID(x.id)">{{ x.name }}</button></td>
```

controller :

```
fetch.controller('direct',function($scope,$http,$window){
        $scope.sendID=function(){
        $http.post("here.php",{'id':$scope.id})
                .success(function(headers,config){
                });
        $window.location.href = '/here.php'; 
    }

});
```

The second page, which I want to pass the id to:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

echo $data->id;

?>
```

When I click any button, the second page says:

"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Any idea about what is wrong?!

Thank you.

Comment: you mean another partial??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be pass id through href:

```
$window.location.href = '/here.php?id=' + $scope.id;
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: what i must write in the second page ?!

Comment: `<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanted it to be accessed in next page pass it as query string
else save the value in $rootscope so that it can be accessed from any controller

Comment: can you help me in the coding ?!